# Android Screen Size Scaling

Tags: android, size, screen, scaling, dpi

I've read some Android docs including the official developer ones, and no doubt there is a lot of complexity to the art-asset problem involving DPI and screen sizes.

I'm simply looking for the answer to: is there any easy way to have good looking art assets without recreating ones for different screens?!

I've tried to make high-resolution assets, but have found the android-scaling always ends up looking like crap?

Is that always the case or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it the other way. Try low/medium resolution assets. That comes out okay in most cases. (And as of now.. the hdpi devices are in minority ) :-)